# Autoload Error: Module has been already defined

Tags: magento-2.1, module, extensions, composer, magento2.1.6

This error shows up when I do the following:

1. DL and paste this extension under DIR>vendor>magento-japan folder [m2-jplocalize](https://github.com/Magento-Japan/m2-jplocalize)
2. Run the following command:

   composer config repositories.veriteworksartifacts artifact \vendor\magento-japan

   composer require magento-japan/m2-jplocalize

   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
3. Then this error shows up:

   Module 'Veriteworks_Region' from '\vendor\magento-japan\m2-jplocalize/region' has been already defined in '/vendor/veriteworks/m2-region'.

Where did I go wrong? Is this the correct way to install this extension?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not. Skip the first step, composer already downloads the extension in step 2